# Invoking AWS Lambda from Node fails with Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: python, node.js, aws-lambda

I just started working with Node, and have this piece of code, which invokes another lambda.

```
const datar = {"name":"Helen","age":"23"};

const params = {
       FunctionName: 'pdf-generator',
       InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
       LogType: 'None',
       Payload: JSON.stringify(datar),

   };
   
   const response: any = await lambda.invoke(params).promise();
```

For some reason the payload is being sent as a dictionary instead of JSON.
Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it?

Here is what I see in the logs:

```
{'name':'Helen','age':23}
```

with the following error message:

```
 error: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: Does the error show up in the lambda from which you execute or in the target lambda?

Comment: The code looks correct, May I know where did you see the mentioned dictionary object? Can post more code to reproduce the issue?